# Convergence of a simple equation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I'm not a mathematician so I am struggling to get even the syntax correct.  But, I'm trying to solve this equation $1/(d-r\cos(\theta))^2$ where $d$ and $r$ are constants and the equation is run over numerous values of theta between 0 and $2\pi$ (ultimately an infinite number of points). If the equation was run over say 11 values between 0 and 2 pi then I am chasing the sum of the 11 values divided by 11.

I think I have the syntax for the sum below but confidence is not high.  I know this thing converges.  I just can't figure out what the simple equation is.

Any help is appreciated.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{(d-r\cos(2k\pi /n))^2}$$

Comment: You presumably want to divide by $n$ in the above expression. Then the limit is $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{(d-r\cos(2\pi x))^2}\,dx$.

Comment: Hi Andre,  That looks correct.  I'm surprised what I submitted even made sense.  But, having a very rudimentary understanding of calculus, can you point me in the right direction on how I now solve that integral?

Comment: In my first post I mentioned dividing by 11 (n).  So, I believe my attempt at the initial equation was wrong and should have been

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n((d-r\cos(2k\pi /n))^2)}$$

Comment: Yes, that's right. As mentioned in my first comment, if we do that then the limit is the integral I wrote down. That integral can be calculated explicitly, at least in principle. A standard but ugly approach is via the substitution $u=\tan(\pi x)$. That leads to a very unpleasant calculation. There are undoubtedly cleverer approaches. Or else one can ask Maple, or Mathematica, or even Wolfram Alpha.